# how to make a widget in my kivy file program scrollable

Tags: python, android, debugging, kivy, kivy-language

I am stuck with this problem, I am not able to make the SetUpScreen Scrollable and therefore my text is cramped and each other. I don't know how to fix it and manage the correct indentation. Any help is greatly appreciated!

here's the main python code

```
# Python code

import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

kivy.require('1.9.0')

class MyRoot(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyRoot, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_next_button_press(self):
        self.screen_manager.current = 'login_screen'

    def on_help_button_press(self):
        self.screen_manager.current = 'help_screen'

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def on_login_button_press(self):
        username = self.ids.username_input.text
        password = self.ids.password_input.text

        print("Username:", username)
        print("Password:", password)

        self.manager.current = 'logfile_screen'


class HelpScreen(Screen):
    def on_setting_up_button_press(self):
        self.manager.current = 'setting_up_screen'

    def on_configure_button_press(self):
        self.manager.current = 'configure_screen'

    def on_using_button_press(self):
        self.manager.current = 'using_screen'
    def on_previous_button_press(self):
        self.manager.current = 'login_screen'

class LogFileScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScrollableScreen(ScrollView, BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ScrollableScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class SetUpScreen(ScrollableScreen, Screen):
    def on_back_button_press(self):
        self.manager.current = 'help_screen'

class ConfigureScreen(ScrollableScreen, Screen):
    def on_back_button_press(self):
        self.manager.current = 'help_screen'

class UsingScreen(ScrollableScreen, Screen):
    def on_back_button_press(self):
        self.manager.current = 'help_screen'

class NeuralRandom(App):
    def build(self):
        root = MyRoot()
        root.screen_manager = root.ids.screen_manager

        root.screen_manager.add_widget(SetUpScreen(name='setting_up_screen'))
        root.screen_manager.add_widget(ConfigureScreen(name='configure_screen'))
        root.screen_manager.add_widget(UsingScreen(name='using_screen'))

        return root

neuralRandom = NeuralRandom()
neuralRandom.run()
```

and here's the chunk of code in the kivy file i'm trying to fix

```
<SetUpScreen>:
    manager: self.manager
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False  # Disable horizontal scrolling
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0.93, 0.87, 0.04, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            Label:
                text: "Setup Home Assistant on a compatible device (E.G., old computer, raspberry pi, etc.):"
                font_size: 30
                color: 0, 0, 0
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'

            Label:
                text: "1. Steps for Raspberry Pi 3/4:"
                font_size: 25
                color: 0, 0, 0
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'

            Label:
                text: 'a. Connect Pi to Local network – Two options:\n' \
                      '    i. Create CONFIG USB Drive\n' \
                      '       1. Format USB Drive as FAT32 or MS-DOS FAT. Name Drive “CONFIG”\n' \
                      '       2. Create Directory called “network"\n' \
                      '       3. Create a file with no extension called “my-network”\n' \
                      '       4. Paste this into file (fill in <Your Wifi Name Here> and <Your Wifi Password Here>\n' \
                      '    ii. Connect Pi to Router via Ethernet Cable\n' \
                      '        1. That’s it… :)\n' \
                      'b. Create Home Assistant Micro-SD\n' \
                      '    i. Install Raspberry Pi Imager\n' \
                      '    ii. Insert SD Card into Computer\n' \
                      '    iii. In Imager select SD card from “Storage”\n' \
                      '    iv. Navigate to “Operating System” -> “Other specific-purpose OS” -> “Home assistants and home automation” -> “Home Assistant” -> Choose version compatible with your Pi version.\n' \
                      '    v. Press “Write”\n' \
                      'c. Start Home Assistant Server\n' \
                      '    i. Insert SD Card into Raspberry Pi\n' \
                      '    ii. Insert USB Drive into Raspberry Pi (if opting with CONFIG USB Drive)\n' \
                      '    iii. Connect Raspberry Pi into power source (at least 5V, 3A)'
                multiline: True
                font_size: 20
                color: 0, 0, 0
                halign: 'center'
                valign: 'middle'

            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                size_hint_y: None
                height: '130dp'
                spacing: '20dp'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0}

            Button:
                text: "Back"
                font_size: 25
                size_hint_x: None
                width: '150dp'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0}
                on_press: root.on_back_button_press()
```

I tried to reformat the text in the third label so that it would go to the next lline but i keep getting indentation errors and i don't know how to fix them. I also added a scrollable class in the main python code but so far it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your `kv` for The `BoxLayout` inside the `ScrollView` use `minimum_height`:

```
<SetUpScreen>:
    manager: self.manager
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x: False  # Disable horizontal scrolling
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            
            # use this to allow the BoxLayout to grow
            size_hint_y: None   
            height: self.minimum_height
```

Then you need to assign a `height` for every widget inside the `BoxLayout`. An easy way to do this for a `Label` is:

```
        Label:
            # assign a height
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
```

The `self.minimum_height` will calculate a height of the `BoxLayout` that is just large enough to contain all the children. But it requires that every child has a specified `height`, so that is why each `Label` should have the above code. You can use that same code for a `Button`. The child `BoxLayout` already has a `height` assigned, so that is fine as it stands.